# calling a random integer variable in code (objective-c, xcode)

Tags: xcode, variables, integer

Im trying to write some code where the computer creates a random integer between 1 and 12 and I want to be able to compare that number elsewhere in my code.  How do I call that number in a method? Im very new to this so any help is appreciated

heres how i called it in the .h

```
int losingVault
```

in the .m this how i create the random number

```
losingVault=rand()%12+2;
```

how do i call that elsewhere in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't a lot to go on.  It seems like you may need some basic help understanding Objective-C.  There are a couple books people like to recommend, [Programming in Objective-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157) by Stephen Kochan is probably the most popular.

So, the way your example code is written, `losingVault` will probably have visibility in the entire class in which it was defined.  If you look in your .h file, `int losingVault;` is probably within an `@interface {ClassName}` block.  In your .m file, there should be a matching `@implementation {ClassName}` block.  Anywhere inside that block should be able to access the variable by just calling `losingVault`.  You could make that variable visible outside of that class in a number of ways.

I hope this helps.